# XE7 Firemonkey application get "argument out of range"

Tags: delphi-xe7, firemonkey-style, firemonkey

I'm making a multi-device application whit Rad Studio XE7.
Sometimes when i want save my last modify on a Form, Rad Studio raises an exception "Argument out of range" but don't give me any information on where is the problem.
Detail of error report this:

```
[067B425F]{fmx210.bpl  }
FMX.Types.{System.Generics.Collections}TList.SetCapacity
(Line 737, "System.Generics.Collections.pas" + 1) + $1
[067B1703]{fmx210.bpl  } FMX.Types.RegisterShortCuts (Line 7266,
"FMX.Types.pas" + 23) + $7 [067448C7]{fmx210.bpl  }
FMX.Styles..TStyleReader (Line 351, "FMX.Styles.pas" + 0) + $132E
[067448D6]{fmx210.bpl  } FMX.Styles.TStyleReader.SetName (Line 368,
"FMX.Styles.pas" + 0) + $2 [067449CE]{fmx210.bpl  }
FMX.Styles.TStyleStreaming.SameStyle (Line 404, "FMX.Styles.pas" + 1)
+ $17 [067177F4]{fmx210.bpl  } FMX.Controls.DoWrite (Line 5896, "FMX.Controls.pas" + 2) + $C [06717847]{fmx210.bpl  }
FMX.Controls.TStyleBook.DefineProperties (Line 5902,
"FMX.Controls.pas" + 0) + $B [50161682]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Classes.TWriter.WriteProperties (Line 11571,
"System.Classes.pas" + 19) + $8 [50160EE9]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Classes.TWriter.WriteData (Line 11381, "System.Classes.pas" +
30) + $6 [5016C1F3]{rtl210.bpl  } System.Classes.TComponent.WriteState
(Line 15547, "System.Classes.pas" + 0) + $3 [50160CBF]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Classes.TWriter.WriteComponent (Line 11333,
"System.Classes.pas" + 18) + $8 [067A8F01]{fmx210.bpl  }
FMX.Types.TFmxObject.GetChildren (Line 4750, "FMX.Types.pas" + 7) +
$17 [06760403]{fmx210.bpl  } FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.Notification
(Line 3567, "FMX.Forms.pas" + 1) + $1 [5005F532]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.@CallDynaInst (Line 16299, "System.pas" + 4) + $0
[50160FFA]{rtl210.bpl  } System.Classes.TWriter.WriteData (Line 11403,
"System.Classes.pas" + 52) + $16 [5016C1F3]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Classes.TComponent.WriteState (Line 15547, "System.Classes.pas"
+ 0) + $3 [50160CBF]{rtl210.bpl  } System.Classes.TWriter.WriteComponent (Line 11333,
"System.Classes.pas" + 18) + $8 [5016114E]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Classes.TWriter.WriteDescendent (Line 11431,
"System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $4 [211357A3]{designide210.bpl}
ComponentDesigner.WriteStream (Line 4184, "ComponentDesigner.pas" +
11) + $7 [21135870]{designide210.bpl}
ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.WriteRootStream (Line 4207,
"ComponentDesigner.pas" + 5) + $B [21132540]{designide210.bpl}
ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.GetRootStream (Line 2936,
"ComponentDesigner.pas" + 14) + $5 [211388F6]{designide210.bpl}
ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.Save (Line 5194,
"ComponentDesigner.pas" + 1) + $2 [211389BE]{designide210.bpl}
ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.Save (Line 5208,
"ComponentDesigner.pas" + 15) + $12 [21D7CF56]{delphicoreide210.bpl}
DelphiModule.TPascalCodeMgrModHandler.SaveFile (Line 1589,
"DelphiModule.pas" + 2) + $8 [206A6F84]{coreide210.bpl}
SourceModule.TCodeISourceModule.SaveFile (Line 1514,
"SourceModule.pas" + 2) + $22 [206A4604]{coreide210.bpl}
SourceModule.TSourceModule.SaveFile (Line 656, "SourceModule.pas" + 3)
+ $1F [2087C1AC]{coreide210.bpl} DocModul.TDocModule.TheMalteseFalcon (Line 1438, "DocModul.pas" + 60) + $2 [500F11ED]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Rtti.RawInvoke (Line 7090, "System.Rtti.pas" + 46) + $0
[500F15DF]{rtl210.bpl  } System.Rtti.Invoke (Line 7289,
"System.Rtti.pas" + 57) + $6 [500E7BBA]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Rtti.TRttiInstanceMethodEx.DispatchInvoke (Line 5409,
"System.Rtti.pas" + 101) + $20 [500F1A74]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Rtti.TRttiMethod.Invoke (Line 7980, "System.Rtti.pas" + 1) +
$11 [2087BE24]{coreide210.bpl} DocModul.TDocModule.Save (Line 1362,
"DocModul.pas" + 3) + $22 [206A5731]{coreide210.bpl}
SourceModule.TSourceModule.Save (Line 1005, "SourceModule.pas" + 13) +
$7 [20880E20]{coreide210.bpl} DocModul.SaveModifiedModules (Line 3584,
"DocModul.pas" + 57) + $3 [0041FEA5]{bds.exe     }
AppMain.{System.Generics.Collections}TList.IndexOf
(Line 1151, "System.Generics.Collections.pas" + 0) + $1
[5016D523]{rtl210.bpl  } System.Classes.TBasicAction.Execute (Line
16099, "System.Classes.pas" + 3) + $7 [505AC25A]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.ActnList.TCustomAction.Execute (Line 259, "Vcl.ActnList.pas" + 19)
+ $35 [5016D3A7]{rtl210.bpl  } System.Classes.TBasicActionLink.Execute (Line 16010, "System.Classes.pas" + 2) + $7 [505C316C]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.Controls.TControl.Click (Line 7346, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 7) + $7
[5063F950]{vcl210.bpl  } Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolButton.Click (Line 21481,
"Vcl.ComCtrls.pas" + 0) + $0 [505C3631]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.Controls.TControl.WMLButtonUp (Line 7487, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 7)
+ $6 [505C2C15]{vcl210.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7232, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6 [5016E218]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 16600, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[505C2850]{vcl210.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 7010,
"Vcl.Controls.pas" + 10) + $8 [505C6E12]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.Controls.GetControlAtPos (Line 9773, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 4) + $75
[505C6EDA]{vcl210.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.ControlAtPos (Line
9796, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 13) + $E [505C2850]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform (Line 7010, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 10) +
$8 [505C6FA8]{vcl210.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.IsControlMouseMsg
(Line 9820, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 15) + $29 [505C755E]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9989, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 104)
+ $6 [50641A65]{vcl210.bpl  } Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar.UpdateButtonState (Line 22759, "Vcl.ComCtrls.pas" + 11) + $27 [50641AA6]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar.UpdateButtonStates (Line 22770,
"Vcl.ComCtrls.pas" + 3) + $4 [50644444]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar.WndProc (Line 24345, "Vcl.ComCtrls.pas" + 104) +
$6 [505C6D1C]{vcl210.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line
9750, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6 [5016E218]{rtl210.bpl  }
System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 16600, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[507176C9]{vcl210.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.CancelHint (Line
11181, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 6) + $D [5071635B]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10352, "Vcl.Forms.pas" +
23) + $1 [5071639E]{vcl210.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage
(Line 10382, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4 [507166D1]{vcl210.bpl  }
Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10520, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

I think that the problem lies in the StyleBook component where I have defined some designs so that some parameters can only be modified by them.
it's frustrating that a commercial software doesn't give the opportunity at least to bypass the problem.Enough for me to understand what not to do.

Comment: Unfortunately your call stack is unreadable. I can't save it without effort that I don't want to invest. Can you please edit it so that we can make sense of it. That said, this appears to be a fault in the IDE. You need to report this to the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Seens to be the TListView problem. Try to clear listview fields and clear search box if exists.